# BootstrapV4 - Can't push a span to the right

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-4

In the following code (react isn't important here), I'm using the bootstrapV4 class "text-sm-right". It works perfectly for my `<button>`, but it doesn't for my post.categories `<span>` which remain on the left. I can't make it work and I don't explain it. Is someone having an explanation ?

```
  renderPosts() {
    return this.props.posts.map((post) => {
      return (
        <li className="list-group-item" key={post.id}>
          <span className="text-sm-right">{post.categories}</span>
          <strong>{post.title}</strong>
        </li>
      );
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div className="text-sm-right post-new-button">
          <Link to="/posts/new" className="btn btn-primary">Add post</Link>
        </div>
        <h3>Posts</h3>
        <ul className="list-group">
          {this.renderPosts()}
        </ul>
      </div>
    );
  }
```

Here is a screenshot of the rendered site, button positioned as wanted but categories remaining on the left...
[image: Blog post with failing text-sm-right]

Comment: The difference is that you assign the `text-sm-right` class to the _parent_ of the button; that's what makes it work. The class doesn't do much more than give a `text-align: right` style to the element.

Answer (score 0):

`.list-group-item` has `display: flex` by default. This means that all you have to do is to add *justify-content-between* class to your `<li>` and move your  declaration one line bottom.

Your renderPosts method should look as follow:

  `renderPosts() {
    return this.props.posts.map((post) => {
      return (
        <li className="list-group-item justify-content-between" key={post.id}>
          <strong>{post.title}</strong>
          <span>{post.categories}</span>
        </li>
      );
    });
  }`

You can find an example of this approach on [bootstrap documentation](http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/list-group/#with-badges)